# Why maven downloaded a shorter version for dependency jar?

Tags: java, maven

I am using below configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

And I can see the depended **poi** version is **3.14** in **poi-ooxml-3.14.pom**.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But in the output of dependency tree. The poi **3.10.1** was downloaded, how could it happen? What's the rule for it? Thanks.

[image]

Below(mvn dependency:tree) is the only place that contains 3.10.1.

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.03:compile
```

Comment: You might have a transitive dependency, one your other dependencies depend on the version you don't want. try  - mvn dependency:tree command and check, which other dependency get 3.10.1 version.

Comment: I updated my post, I run 'mvn dependency:tree > a.txt' and seach for '3.10.1', only found the 3.10.1 is the child of org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting   **poi 3.10.1** because of  org.apache.poi - poi-ooxml-schemas transitive dependency, and it overrides your actual dependency declaration.
You should try below entries in you pom.xml, to avoid unwanted version of **poi**

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>3.14</version>
            <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, but even it's a transitive dependency, why the version is not the same as the version in poi-ooxml-3.14.pom. The version in poi-ooxml-3.14.pom. is <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: And I found that the ooxml-schemas only depend on xmlbeans, not poi

Comment: [INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10.1:compile -  here is the dependency as you mentioned in your question, secondly about version, transitive dependency version override your POM dependency version because your org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.14 depends on this version only and if the customize version from POM considered it could created issue at run time